# What code/statement is used when you want the different function executed at the same time in Arduino UNO programming?

Tags: c++, arduino, arduino-uno, arduino-c++

I wanted to execute a simple loop in Arduino UNO at the same time, but I don't know what statement/code use to able to execute it at the same time.

I've tried the while loop and having a time include starting. But since the function is separated from one another in the loop. The execution of the led is the 1st function and 2nd function in different direction. But I want them to be executed at the same time.

```
void loop() {
  // loop from the highest pin to the lowest:
  for (int thisPin = 2; thisPin >= 0; thisPin--) {
    // turn the pin on:
    digitalWrite(ledPins[thisPin], HIGH);
    delay(timer);
    // turn the pin off:
    digitalWrite(ledPins[thisPin], LOW);
  }


  // loop from the lowest pin to the highest:
  for (int thisPin = 0; thisPin < pinCount; thisPin++) {
    // turn the pin on:
    digitalWrite(ledPins[thisPin], HIGH);
    delay(timer);
    // turn the pin off:
    digitalWrite(ledPins[thisPin], LOW);

  }


}
```

It turns out that the execution is executed in function from the highest pin to lowest pin. Then, the lowest pin to the highest pin. Instead of executed at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

Arduino doesn't have the usual capabilities to run tasks in parallel (it doesn't have multithreading). There are however some workarounds. See https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/286/how-can-i-create-multiple-running-threads for more details.

Fortunately in your case you don't need to run the loops in parallel. You can rethink your algorithm in one loop by turning at the same time the pins at opposite sides. Something like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < pinCount; ++i) {
    // turn the pins on:
    digitalWrite(ledPins[i], HIGH);
    digitalWrite(ledPins[pinCount - i - 1], HIGH);

    delay(timer);

    // turn the pins off:
    digitalWrite(ledPins[i], HIGH);
    digitalWrite(ledPins[pinCount - i - 1], LOW);
}
```

Comment: I just figured it out 

```
  // loop from the lowest pin to the highest:
for (int thisPin = 3; thisPin < pinCount; thisPin++) {
    // turn the pins on:
    digitalWrite(ledPins[thisPin], HIGH);
    digitalWrite(ledPins[pinCount - thisPin - 1 ], HIGH);

    delay(timer);

    // turn the pins off:
    digitalWrite(ledPins[thisPin], LOW);
    digitalWrite(ledPins[pinCount - thisPin - 1], LOW);
}  
```

Now it's working both sides. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do multiple things at the same time, this example here is very useful https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=223286.0 while they may technically be out of sync it would be on a tiny scale